# Was bedeutet "Übergreisung"?

Tags: noun, meaning-in-context

Beispielsatz:

> Chinesisch, im Jahre 2005 noch auf Rang 6, wird 2025 die zweitwichtigste Wirtschaftssprache der Welt sein, allerdings wird die Wachstumsdynamik Chinas wegen einer extremen **Übergreisung** als Folge der Ein-Kind-Politik deutlich abnehmen.

Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Wort "Übergreisung" gibt es nicht wirklich, da hat wohl jemand "Vergreisung" und "Überalterung" durcheinandergemischt.

Hits in Google:

- "Übergreisung"  156
- "Vergreisung"   116000
- "Überalterung"  870000

Comment: Zumindest wird das Wort zweifellos verstanden.

Comment: Wobei *Vergreisung* in dem zitierten Zusammenhang nicht passt.

Comment: Gut beobachtet! Bei den 156 (mittlerweile 158) Hits sind aber so viele Mehrfachtreffer dabei, dass es in Wirklichkeit vielleicht nur 20 sind, wo das Wort wirklich benutzt wird.

Answer (score 5):

"Greis" ist ein (sehr) alter Mensch, "Übergreisung", oder "Überalterung" bedeutet also, dass in einer Gesellschaft die Zahl älterer Menschen gegenüber der Zahl jüngerer Menschen stark ausgeprägt ist.

Answer (score 4):

It means an overwhelming amount of old people. A *Greis* is an old man or woman.

Comment: warum antwortest du auf eine deutsche Frage in englisch?

Comment: Gewohnheit, Verzeihung.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, die Mediziner verwenden dieses Wort `Greis` etwas anders und beziehen sich dabei auf den allgemeinen Alterungszustand. Nicht alle Menschen altern biologisch gleich schnell.

Der Begriff `Greis` ist mehr an den durch das Altern verursachten Veränderungen orientiert, als am Kalender. Der Begriff `Vergreisung`, auf einen Einzelnen angewandt, wird in diesem Sinne angewandt.

Ich denke auch nicht, dass 80-Jährige, die `fit-wie-ein-Turnschuh` sind, volkstümlich als `Greis` bezeichnet werden.

Im Zusammenhang mit **Übergreisung** orientiert sich der Begriff allerdings eher an der **Arbeitsfähigkeit** oder der **Erwerbstätigkeit**. In diesem Bereich verschieben sich die Grenzen zurzeit bei uns nach oben (Stichwort Rentenalter).

Answer (score 0):

Im Zusammenhang mit der genannten ["Ein-Kind-Poltik"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein-Kind-Politik) würde ich auch eher das Wort Überalterung als Symnonym für Übergreisung verwenden.
Um die Bevölkerungsdichte in China in den Griff zu bekommen, gibt es gewissen staatliche Förderungen für Familien mit nur einem Kind. Bekommen Paare in einem Land über einen langen Zeitraum jedoch weniger als durchschnittlich zwei Kinder, so wird das Durschnittsalter der Menschen in diesem Land stark ansteigen.
Kurz um: Übergreisung = Überalterung = sehr viel mehr ältere Menschen.